# Creating Text/Code Editor from Scratch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, text-editor

I need some help on looking for references in building a complex text/code editor, not just a simple one that you can only write and read plain text. What I'm actually aiming for is a text editor with Line Numbers display on the side and code highlightinh and lexing. Simply put, like a notepad++ or a dreamweaver style of text/code editor. And I want to build it on C#.

I won't exactly ask for codes, but some samples would really be a great help. Something I can base my work on, concepts, etc. I just really need something to start to. Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: SharpDevelop is Open Source and you can peek in source code

Comment: I might add that if SharpDevelop is to complex to understand, you still should look in open source, I'm sure there is a lot of such code on codeplex.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. I will try them. :]

Comment: If it helps anyone in the future, I have been working on a text editor project for the past two years and have made some amazing progress, feel free to take a look at my project for inspiration or for examples of how to implement different components to create a decent end-product. Here is the link: https://github.com/Hexman768/Notepad-Sharp

Answer (score 4):

You may find the following interesting:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxHighlighting.aspx